# How to download war from Tomcat manager

Tags: tomcat

I've successfully deployed war files on Tomcat 6, however, I'd like to download those war files from the manager app. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you would need to log in to your server via SSH or some other way and copy the WAR file from CATALINA_BASE/webapps directory.